# SimpleBlobDetector cannot run

Tags: c++, opencv, blob

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I'm running into a problem and I need your help. I'm having a threshold mat and I'm trying to detect any blob on it. My setup is:

```
    cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
    params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 10.0;  // minimum 10 pixels between blobs
    params.filterByArea = true;         // filter my blobs by area of blob
    params.minArea = 1000;              // min 1000 pixels squared
    params.maxArea = 10000;             // max 10000 pixels squared
    params.filterByColor = true;
    params.blobColor = 255;
    Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> detector = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> myBlobs;
    detector->detect(fgMaskMOG2, myBlobs);
    drawKeypoints(fgMaskMOG2, myBlobs, fgMaskMOG2);
    imshow("FG Mask MOG 2", fgMaskMOG2);
```

But the program stopped after running it without showing keypoint highlighted on my image. This is the Mat fgMaskMOG2, a binary frame, created before those lines of code:
[image: pic]

I'm using opencv 3. The problem was at the line  detector->detect(fgMaskMOG2, myBlobs); I've read other topics and don't think the problem is in the code because other people have done the same. I tried to converted the frame to CV_GRAY2RGB and CV_8UC1, but it doesn't fix the problem. I also tried to tweaked the params properties but it doesn't change anything. Any idea guys?

Comment: What did you find while researching the problem?

Comment: Why am I getting the downvotes guys? :)
I'm still researching and debugging, no luck yet.

Comment: You're probably getting down votes because you did not indicate in any way that you even researched the problem. This community can be unforgiving if you don't play the game. I've had the same problem you're having, so don't feel too bad.

Comment: I added something that I tried, I really need help cause I'm stuck and don't know how to fix. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I found was I didn't use the correct library. I use opencv_world.dll for Debug mode. I switched to Release mode and it solved the problem.